# beautifulsoup how to recombine words

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Some of the words outputted are split when running this code. Like the word "tolerances" is split into "tole rances". I looked at the html source and it seems that's how the page was created.

There are also many other places where the word is split. How do I recombine them before writing to text?

```
import requests, codecs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Comment

path='C:\\Users\\jason\\Google Drive\\python\\'

def tag_visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['sup']:
        return False
    if isinstance(element, Comment):
        return False
    return True

ticker = 'TSLA'
quarter = '18Q2'    
mark1= 'ITEM 1A'
mark2= 'UNREGISTERED SALES'
url_new='https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1318605/000156459018019254/tsla-10q_20180630.htm'

def get_text(url,mark1,mark2):
    html = requests.get(url) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

    for hr in soup.select('hr'):
        hr.find_previous('p').extract()

    texts = soup.findAll(text=True)

    visible_texts = filter(tag_visible, texts) 
    text=u" ".join(t.strip() for t in visible_texts)

    return text[text.find(mark1): text.find(mark2)]

text = get_text(url_new,mark1,mark2)

file=codecs.open(path + "test.txt", 'w', encoding='utf8')
file.write (text)
file.close()
```

Comment: It looks like you are joining the text together with spaces here: `text=u" ".join(t.strip() for t in visible_texts)`

Comment: Don't use `codecs.open()`. On Python 3 use `open()`, on Python 2, `io.open()`. The codecs codebase has a lot of performance and implementation issues when it comes to file I/O.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are dealing with *HTML formatted with Microsoft Word*. Don't extract text and try to process it without that context.

The section you want to process is clearly delineated with `<a name="...">` tags, lets start with selecting all elements with the `<a name="ITEM_1A_RISK_FACTORS">` marker, all the way up to but not including the `<a name="ITEM2_UNREGISTERED_SALES">` marker:

```
def sec_section(soup, item_name):
    """iterate over SEC document paragraphs for the section named item_name

    Item name must be a link target, starting with ITEM
    """

    # ask BS4 to find the section
    elem = soup.select_one('a[name={}]'.format(item_name))
    # scan up to the parent text element
    # html.parser does not support <text> but lxml does
    while elem.parent is not soup and elem.parent.name != 'text':
        elem = elem.parent

    yield elem
    # now we can yield all next siblings until we find one that
    # is also contains a[name^=ITEM] element:
    for elem in elem.next_siblings:
        if not isinstance(elem, str) and elem.select_one('a[name^=ITEM]'):
            return
        yield elem
```

This function gives us all child nodes from the `<text>` node in the HTML document that start at a paragraph containing a specific link target, all the way through to the next link target that names an `ITEM`.

Next, the usual Word cleanup task is to remove `<font>` tags, `style` attributes:

```
def clean_word(elem):
    if isinstance(elem, str):
        return elem
    # remove last-rendered break markers, non-rendering but messy
    for lastbrk in elem.select('a[name^=_AEIOULastRenderedPageBreakAEIOU]'):
        lastbrk.decompose()
    # remove font tags and styling from the document, leaving only the contents
    if 'style' in elem.attrs:
        del elem.attrs['style']
    for e in elem:  # recursively do the same for all child nodes
        clean_word(e)
    if elem.name == 'font':
        elem = elem.unwrap()
    return elem
```

The [`Tag.unwrap()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) is what'll most help your case, as the text is divided up almost arbitrarily by `<font>` tags.

Now it's suddenly trivial to extract the text cleanly:

```
for elem in sec_section(soup, 'ITEM_1A_RISK_FACTORS'):
    clean_word(elem)
    if not isinstance(elem, str):
        elem = elem.get_text(strip=True)
    print(elem)
```

This outputs, among the rest of the text:

```
•that the equipment and processes which we have selected for Model 3 production will be able to accurately manufacture high volumes of Model 3 vehicles within specified design tolerances and with high quality;
```

The text is now properly joined up, no re-combining required any more.

The whole section is still in a table but `clean_word()` cleaned this up now to the much more reasonable:

```html
<div align="left">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<p> </p></td>
<td valign="top">
<p>•</p></td>
<td valign="top">
<p>that the equipment and processes which we have selected for Model 3 production will be able to accurately manufacture high volumes of Model 3 vehicles within specified design tolerances and with high quality;</p></td></tr></table></div>
```

so you can use smarter text extraction techniques to further ensure a clean text conversion here; you could convert such bullet tables to a `*` prefix, for example:

```
def convert_word_bullets(soup, text_bullet="*"):
    for table in soup.select('div[align=left] > table'):
        div = table.parent
        bullet = div.find(string='\u2022')
        if bullet is None:
            # not a bullet table, skip
            continue
        text_cell = bullet.find_next('td')
        div.clear()
        div.append(text_bullet + ' ')
        for i, elem in enumerate(text_cell.contents[:]):
            if i == 0 and elem == '\n':
                continue  # no need to include the first linebreak
            div.append(elem.extract())
```

In addition, you probably want to skip the page breaks too (a combination of `<p>[page number]</p>` and `<hr/>` elements), if you run

```
for pagebrk in soup.select('p ~ hr[style^=page-break-after]'): 
    pagebrk.find_previous_sibling('p').decompose()
    pagebrk.decompose()
```

This is more explicit than your own version, where you remove all `<hr/>` elements and preceding `<p>` element regardless of whether they are actually siblings.

Execute both *before* cleaning up your Word HTML. Combined with your function that together becomes:

```
def get_text(url, item_name):
    response = requests.get(url) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    for pagebrk in soup.select('p ~ hr[style^=page-break-after]'): 
        pagebrk.find_previous_sibling('p').decompose()
        pagebrk.decompose()

    convert_word_bullets(soup)
    cleaned_section = map(clean_word, sec_section(soup, item_name))

    return ''.join([
        elem.get_text(strip=True) if elem.name else elem
        for elem in cleaned_section])


text = get_text(url, 'ITEM_1A_RISK_FACTORS')
with open(os.path.join(path, 'test.txt'), 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

This page markup is really bad. You will need to remove excess tags to fix your issue. Luckily for you, beautifulsoup can do the heavy-lifting. The code below will remove all `font` tags.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
for font in soup.find_all('font'):
    font.unwrap()
```